# If I want to append "\" in a string before every white space. how do i do that?

Tags: java, string, substring, charat

1. Suppose input String is Abc def ghi.. i want result to be like this Abc\ def\ ghi

   ```
   Date=122
   Shipper\ Id=11
   Bill\ No=54433
   Weight=431
   Shipper\ Last\ Name=aaa
   Shipper\ First\ Name=cdcx
   ```

Comment: Look up `replace()` and `replaceAll()` methods of `String` class.Also, you need to escape the `"\"`

Comment: replace ALL the `" "`(whitespaces) with `"\\ "`

Comment: What happens if you have multiple spaces? `test  name`

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
string s = "Abc" + "\\"+ "def" + "\\" + "ghi";
```

or you may try to replcae your space(`" "`) with `\`

```
string result  = s.replaceAll(" ","\\ ");
```

Comment: A small note - OP wants to append, rather than replace, the spaces.

Comment: @JaeHeonLee:- Thats why I have used `"\\ "` instead of `"\\"` There is a spcace in `"\\ "`

Comment: @R.T: I want to append "\" before every white space. i think using replace All white space will be removed right? dnt want that

Comment: @R.T. - For regex, you will need `\\\\\`

Comment: @SharmishthaKulkarni:- No as I commented the white space will be presereved as I have used `"\\ "` not `"\\"`. Please note there is a space in `"\\ "`

Comment: @TheLostMind:- Do you mean this:- `s.replaceAll("(\\s)", "\\\\ ");`

Comment: No I meant 4 slashes followed by a space.  You need to escape the slash for the regex engine as wel.

Comment: @TheLostMind:- OK but what is the problem with `string result  = s.replaceAll(" ","\\ ");`

Comment: @R.T. - Please execute it and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Abc def ghi".replaceAll("(?=\\s)", "\\\\")
```

Comment: Um... because `replaceAll("\\s", "\\\\")` would remove the whitespace?

Comment: I meant you could actually just find a space and replace it with a backslash and space.

Comment: That would insert a backslash before every space, but not before other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String s= " Abc def gh";
System.out.println(s.replace(" ", "\\ "));
```

EDIT:

```
    String s = " Abc def gh";
    // System.out.println(s.replace(" ", "\\ "));

    File f = new File("trail.properties");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(f);

    fileWriter.write(s.replace(" ", "\\ "));

    fileWriter.close();
```

Output:

```
\ Abc\ def\ gh
```

Comment: nothing changes if we use \\. result is same as before i.e abc def and using  \\\\ generates result like this abc\\ def if i store it in a properties file

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to match all whitespace `\s` and prepend `\`.
In the replacement pattern you need to escape the literal `\` with another backslash: `\\`.

`String result = searchText.replaceAll("(\\s)", "\\\$1");`

Comment: when i store the result in properties file it is getting saved as abc\\ def instead of abc\ def. i want single slash only

Answer (score 0):

The `\` need not be escaped in the replace string, thus

```
output = input.replaceAll("(?=\\s)", "\\")
```

Will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and [replaceAll(String regex,String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

`\s` matches every white Whitespace characters and`+` matches the preceding pattern element one or more times.

So please try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String s="Abc    def     ghi";
        String output = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "\\\\");
        System.out.println(output);// output :Abc\def\ghi
    }
```